# IEnumerable - Update objects inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I have a really simple program that creates a bunch of objects and iterates through them to set each object's `Priority` property.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var obj in ObjectCreator.CreateObjectsWithPriorities())
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Object #{0} has priority {1}",
                                         obj.Id, obj.Priority));
}

class ObjectCreator
{
    public static IEnumerable<ObjectWithPriority> CreateObjectsWithPriorities()
    {
        var objs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => new ObjectWithPriority() { Id = i });
        ApplyPriorities(objs);
        return objs;
    }

    static void ApplyPriorities(IEnumerable<ObjectWithPriority> objs)
    {
        foreach (var obj in objs)
        {
            obj.Priority = obj.Id * 10;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Set priority of object #{0} to {1}", obj.Id, obj.Priority));
        }
    }
}

class ObjectWithPriority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting the `IEnumerable` in the Main method to contain objects with modified priorities. However, all of them have the default value 0.
Here is the log:

```
Set priority of object #1 to 10 
Set priority of object #2 to 20 
Set priority of object #3 to 30 
Object #1 has priority 0 
Object #2 has priority 0 
Object #3 has priority 0
```

What is the reason for suche behavior and what should I change here in order to get my priorities working?

Comment: Two important facts you must internalize about LINQ: (1) The value of a query expression is a *query*, and (2) a query is executed *when the query is executed*. These statement may seem to be tautologies, but your code shows that you did not believe them; you believed that the value of a query is the execution of the query, and that executing it twice only executes it once.

Comment: @EricLippert, you're right, I always thought of IEnumerable as a sequence of elements I can _enumerate_ through (as the name suggests), not as a query representation. It also seemed to make sense that if I only needed to loop through the sequence (and never add/remove elements), I could safely use IEnumerable throughout my whole program without calling ToList. As many books/articles suggest, "you should use the most general type possible" for passing objects between methods/classes/programs, and that's what I was trying to do here. Now I see it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var objs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => new ObjectWithPriority() { Id = i });
```

You're simply creating a lazily evaluated iterator, this doesn't allocate an array/list to store the `ObjectWithPriorty` you project. Each time you enumerate the iterator, it will iterate the values again and project an `ObjectWithPriority` for each iteration, but will discard them.

What you want to do is materialize the query before you pass it, so later you'll actually modifying the already allocated list/array. This can be achieved using `Enumerable.ToList` or `Enumerable.ToArray`:

```
public static IEnumerable<ObjectWithPriority> CreateObjectsWithPriorities()
{
    var objs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => new ObjectWithPriority() { Id = i })
                                .ToList();
    ApplyPriorities(objs);
    return objs;
}
```

You could additional use `Enumerable.Range` instead of allocating a fixed size array, which will lazily project the numbers as requested:

```
var objs = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new ObjectWithPriority { Id = i })
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination! This whole IEnumerable concept is a little confusing. So if I have a method that reads some external data (i.e. a file or a DB table) and converts it into my domain model objects, should I maybe change its return type to `List` instead of `IEnumerable` to avoid such problems when other code manipulates the data this method returns?

Comment: When you're querying a database, you should be very careful with any `IEnumerable<T>` you return to the caller. For example, if you hand such enumerable to  a caller, and he enumerates it multiple times with LINQ or a `foreach` statement, then the query will be executed multiple times. Perhaps, you're better off returning a `T[]` or an `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand what is happening in your program, you should think of this expression

```
var objs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => new ObjectWithPriority() { Id = i });
```

as a *query*, not as a sequence/list/collection of objects.

But it is obvious from your code that in this particular program you don't need a query. You need a collection that has a finite number of objects and that returns the same objects every time you loop through it using `foreach`.

So a decent thing to do would be to use `ICollection<ObjectWithPriority>` instead of `IEnumerable<ObjectWithPriority>`. This would better represent the program's logic and help avoid some mistakes/misinterpretations like the one you stumbled upon.

The code could be modified as follows:

```
public static ICollection<ObjectWithPriority> CreateObjectsWithPriorities()
{
    IEnumerable<ObjectWithPriority> queryThatProducesObjectsWithPriorities = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => new ObjectWithPriority() { Id = i }); // just for clarification
    ICollection<ObjectWithPriority> objectsWithPriorities = queryThatProducesObjectsWithPriorities.ToList();
    ApplyPriorities(objectsWithPriorities);
    return objectsWithPriorities;
}

static void ApplyPriorities(ICollection<ObjectWithPriority> objs)
{
    foreach (var obj in objs)
    {
        obj.Priority = obj.Id * 10;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Set priority of object #{0} to {1}", obj.Id, obj.Priority));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the Answer of [Yuval Itzchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870803/yuval-itzchakov):

If you want to lazy-load the priority of your objects you could:

Define your `ApplyPriorities()` Method just for one object and use it in the select-Method OR add a delegate to your `ObjectWithPriority` class wich calculates the Priority like shown in the code below:

```
class ObjectWithPriority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private int? priority;
    public int Priority {
        get
        {
            return (priority.HasValue ? priority.Value : (priority = PriorityProvider(this)).Value);

        }

        set { priority = value; }
    }

    Func<ObjectWithPriority, int> PriorityProvider { get; set; }

    public ObjectWithPriority(Func<ObjectWithPriority, int> priorityProvider = null)
    {
        PriorityProvider = priorityProvider ?? (obj => 10 * obj.Id);
    }
}
```